# Bug in moment.js format datetime doesn't work when using .calendar() method

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hi I am struggling to format datetime with `moment.js 2.9.0`.

It just doesn't work, it doesn't format in my datetime format.

My code below:

```
moment('2014-07-01 02:20',['YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm']).calendar();
```

Results:

```
"07/01/2014"   it is MM/DD/YYYY
```

Should be `01/07/2014` `DD/MM/YYYY`

Actually, how can I format the result from the `calendar()`? I think it is using the format: `MM/DD/YYYY` as default.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/

This is giving me problems, does any one have the solution or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to click the link to 'can be customised' in moment.js docs.

To customise calendar() output you need to do:

```
moment.locale('en', {
    calendar : {
        lastDay : '[Yesterday at] LT',
        sameDay : '[Today at] LT',
        nextDay : '[Tomorrow at] LT',
        lastWeek : '[last] dddd [at] LT',
        nextWeek : 'dddd [at] LT',
        sameElse : 'DD/MM/YYY'
    }
});
```

then

```
moment('2014-07-01 02:20',['YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm']).calendar();
```

will return `01/07/2014`.

Comment: Yeah I didn't see it, great!

Comment: Always amused by the use of "locale". None of the data relates to locality, they're just formatting preferences. ;-)